# how to pass path parameter to AWS api gateway using AWS Step function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-step-functions

In aws step function i need to call api gateway endpoint with path parameters from previous state values.
[image]

Step Function Code (Api Gateway Call)

```
"API Gateway Request": {
  "Type": "Task",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::apigateway:invoke",
  "Parameters": {
    "ApiEndpoint": "****.amazonaws.com",
    "Method": "GET",
    "Headers": {
      "Accept": [
        "application/json"
      ]
    },
    "Stage": "dev",
    "Path": "/sample/$.id",
    "AuthType": "IAM_ROLE"
  },
  "InputPath": "$.id",
  "Next": "Lambda Invoke",
  "ResultPath": "$.myStateInput"
}
```

Input to this state:

```
{ "id": "1231" }
```

Instead of replacing "$.id" as "1231", it just calling url like below
[image]
**Api Gateway:**

[image]

Please tell what i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Did you try with `States.Format('/sample/{}', $.id)`?

Comment: @Marcin yes working.

Comment: Glad it worked out. I added an answer if you don't mind.

Comment: Acceptance of the answer would be appreciated.

Comment: @Marcin please accept my edit to your answer "Path.$": States.Format('/sample/{}', $.id)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the comments, the solution was to use [intrinsic function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html):

```
"Path.$": States.Format('/sample/{}', $.id)
```

**State Code**

```
"API Gateway Request": {
  "Type": "Task",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::apigateway:invoke",
  "Parameters": {
    "ApiEndpoint": "**.amazonaws.com",
    "Method": "GET",
    "Headers": {
      "Accept": [
        "application/json"
      ]
    },
    "Stage": "dev",
    "Path.$": "States.Format('/sample/{}', $.id)",
    "AuthType": "IAM_ROLE"
  },
  "Next": "Lambda Invoke",
  "ResultPath": "$.myStateInput"
}
```